# compiling rule in two scss files to one css rule

Tags: css, sass, compass

I'm pretty new to Sass and have tried googling this and reading through the docs but I can't quite find an answer to this question.

I have two scss files, one for my layout rules and one for design-y things.  In _layout.scss I have:

```
ul.helpToggle {

    li {
        margin-bottom: 2em;
    }
    > li {
        padding-bottom: .5em;
    }
}
```

and in _design.scss I have

```
ul.helpToggle {
    list-style: none;

    > li {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #363635;
    }
}
```

and it is out putting two separate rules in my css file:

```
ul.helpToggle>li {border-bottom: 1px solid #363635;}
```

and

```
ul.helpToggle>li {padding-bottom: .5em;}
```

I would expect the output to be:

```
ul.helpToggle>li {border-bottom: 1px solid #363635;padding-bottom: .5em;}
```

Are my expectations wrong or am I doing something wrong? I am running compass watch to compile the scss files.